# smallest and largest number using python

Tags: python

```
largest = None

smallest = None

while True:

    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        halo = float(num)
    except:
        print("invalid output")
        continue
    for largest in range(halo):
        if largest is None:
            largest = halo
        elif largest > halo:
              largest = halo
    for smallest in range(halo):
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = halo
        elif smallest<halo:
                    smallest = halo
    print("largest is",largest)
    print("smallest is",smallest)
```

i want to print smallest and largest number but im getting a error ***"start must be an integer on line 11"***
i know there will be some other mistake in my code but i want to correct this first

Comment: Please *show* us the **exact** Error and Traceback.

Comment: how can you use `range(float)` ?

Comment: Also what are you inputing to the program

Comment: can you use `int(num)` instead of `float(num)`?

Comment: You need to define if you are expecting int or float  or both. The approach you are using will be defined by that. Arnad is correct in that range takes an int, however this assumes you expect an int.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `range` function should be plain integer [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

You should convert to `int` instead of `float` -

```
halo = int(num)
```